# Flask: accessing application config in other files (anywhere and not just while serving requests)

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I didn't get it clearly from Flask docs. Also, I can see similar stackoverflow questions but I still didn't get my answer, hence asking.

I have a flask application served using gunicorn+gevent. Gunicorn worker process, on start, creates a Flask application. Then it imports some files that setup a few global things, like a udp connection to a statsd server, etc. The setup needs to be done only once i.e. on worker process start and not with every client request. The setup code in the imported files needs access to config variables.

I know that while serving a request I can use the current_app proxy, but not outside a request.

One way can be: put Flask app creation code in a separate file and include it wherever you need access to config.

Ex:
file: mywsgi.py

```
from flask import Flask
application = Flask(__name__)
application.config.from_pyfile('myconfig.cfg')
```

file: mygunicornapp.py

```
from mywsgi import application
import file1
import file2
# import more files
```

file: file1.py

```
from mywsgi import application
# use the application config to setup something
```

file: file2.py

```
from mywsgi import application
# use the application config to setup something
```

Is this the preferred way?

Flask doc says I can create application context explicitly.

Can I push application context, just after creating my flask app, and never pop it. So that the application context is always there as long as my process runs and the current_app proxy will be available application wide even when no request being served?

Ex:

```
from flask import Flask
application = Flask(__name__)
application.config.from_pyfile('myconfig.cfg')
application.app_context().push()
```

Now I should be able to use the current_app proxy anywhere in my code. Thoughts, please!

== Update ==

The files file1.py, file2.py etc are imported for adding routes to the application. They provide the functions that handle my api requests. So the file mygunicornapp.py looks more like:

file: mygunicornapp.py

```
from mywsgi import application

from file1 import API1
@application.route("/api1")
def handle_api1():
    return API1.handler()

from file2 import API2
@application.route("/api2")
def handle_api2():
    return  API2.handler()

# many more routes
```

Now file1 imports many other files and they, in turn, import many more files. Any of these imported files may need access to a config parameter that I have set on the application object. The question is: How do I make the application object available to all these files? Do you suggest that I pass the application object to each file?

Is it possible to just delay adding routes? I mean set routes after current_app context local is available. That means the files will be imported after current_app is available. I tried adding routes to the current_app context local in 'before_first_request' callback. The problem with that is, the very first request returns 404. Subsequent returns give a correct response.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make functions in `file1` and `file2`, and pass the argument `app` into them? Then you can call these functions in your setup code in `mywsgi.py`, using as an argument the app object you just created.

This should work much better than some of the other things you suggested. The different files importing each other is close to a circular import. Pushing an app context is also something that leaves you likely to end up with difficult to understand bugs.

If you create the object `app` in one file and import it from that file everywhere, you basically have a global variable (using a namespace). This is going to cause problem when you want to test your app setup code, or create more than one version of your app for another reason. There is also the issue that you won't be able to import any of `file1`, `file2` *without* creating an app object. While testing these, or possibly re-using some of that code outside of Flask, this will be a pain.

It's much better to create the app object once and pass it around. Having a function which returns the newly created app, which can be imported and called from anywhere, is a common way of organizing a flask app. This file is often called `factory.py`. It makes it easier to create zero, one or more copies of the app, rather than making it more difficult.

Comment: Updated the question. The files file1, file2 and many more are imported for handling the routes. I don't understand how I make the application object available to all of these files. Can't we just defer adding routes till the time current_app is available?